# Dialogflow console returning different result to when sent through the API (Where the wrong timezone is used)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have a DialogFlow agent set up where one intent is used to schedule reminders. I can say something like:

```
"At 5pm remind me to go for a run"
```

And it returns the sentence to remind (in this case 'go for a run') as well as the time to set the reminder using @sys.date-time.

This works as intended, I am able to get the correct time because it just sends the time without a timezone attached.

When I use a command such as:

```
"In 15 minutes remind me to go for a run"
```

it sends the result as the time using the timezone, in this case, the incorrect one.

So right now, a result for the date-time using the API was:

```
2020-11-09T14:20:33+01:00
```

which is an hour more than it should be.

I have checked the DialogFlow agent's default time zone where it is set to:

```
(GMT0:00) Africa/Casablanca
```

Which I am fairly certain is the correct one for London time. However moving to a different timezone changes it and actually gives the correct one for the timezone (Just not my timezone)
Leaving me to wonder if this time zone is broken?

Regardless though, the Dialogflow console on the webpage returns the correct date-time but in a different format using 'startDateTime' and 'endDateTime', something that the agent does not do when sent using the API.

I have checked all configurations within the program and cannot find any evidence of any code giving a new timezone and in fact have tried to add the London timezone when a query is sent but this does not resolve the issue.

Does anyone have any advice on how to solve this?

EDIT:

After receiving a good suggestion from a user I am reminded of the most puzzling part of this issue. Chaning the timezone to GMT -1:00 vs 0:00 actually having a difference of two hours.

Around 1pm I queried it to get the time in 15 minutes.

When it was set to GMT-1:00 Atlantiv/Cape_Verde the time returned is:

```
2020-11-10T12:21:15-01:00
```

When it was set to GMT0:00 Africa/Casablanca the time returned is:

```
2020-11-10T14:22:07+01:00
```

Neither is the correct time and despite the timezone suggesting a 1 hour difference, it is actually 2 hours apart.

Answer (score 0):

For London the correct timezone should be GMT -1, Casablanca Africa is GMT+1, I used this [web page](https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/) to determine this[image].

If you are in London is recommended to configure your agent to sue the correct time zone (GMT-1).[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is something I had actually tried but this does not give the correct time either:

Setting it to GMT-1:00 does it an hour behind, and setting it to GMT00:00 makes it a hour ahead! This has to be an issue with DialogFlow.

I will put more details in an edit in the whole post above

Comment: You need to consider that  London is in (GMT) I'm not sure if this changed this weekend,  Casablanca is (GMT+1) and Cape_Verde is (GMT-1) if this  is in your radar  and you are still facing the issue, I Suggest you to open a [Public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=501190) to contact the Dialogflow team.